# I want to group my list of lists by date and sum the values where the dates match

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like that:

```
l = [['05-05-2015', -40], ['05-05-2015', 30], ['07-05-2015', -75], ['05-05-2015', -40], ['05-05-2015', 120], ['07-05-2015', -150]]
```

I want to group it by date and sum the values where the dates are equal like that:

```
[['05-05-2015', 70], ['07-05-2015', -225]]
```

I found this solution: [python sum up list elements in list of lists based on date as unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47889609/python-sum-up-list-elements-in-list-of-lists-based-on-date-as-unique)

It seems to solve my problem. But I found the code very complex to understand and replicate in my code.

Could someone explain me how I can do this?

Comment: If you already found a solution in the answers to the other question, I'm not sure what an answer to this question could add that is not already written in one of the other answers.

Comment: Have you tried writing a loop like `for date, value in l: ...`?

Comment: I wanted somebody to explain whats happening in the codes of the solutions from that link. For example: ``import itertools
new_data = {a:sum(sum(map(float, i[:-1])) for i in list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(s, key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])}``. I can't understand what I have to modify in this code to make it proper for my problem case

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [['05-05-2015', -40], ['05-05-2015', 30], ['07-05-2015', -75], ['05-05-2015', -40], ['05-05-2015', 120], ['07-05-2015', -150]]

d = {}

for date, value in l:
    d[date] = d.get(date, 0) + value

print(list(d.items()))
```

Output:

```
[('05-05-2015', 70), ('07-05-2015', -225)]
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the way the output is genereted. Do you think that the way the guy who got the "best answer" in the link I mentioned in the question could be more computationally efficient?

``import itertools
new_data = {a:sum(sum(map(float, i[:-1])) for i in list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(s, key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])}``

If yes, would it be too much work to explain what is happening in this code? How could I adapt it to make it work in my list?

Comment: @ApoloReis indeed way too much computing when you can do it in the same loop. The accepted answer, will create a dict of list, then iterate thro the newly created dict to sum each list items. You may just update the value of the dict you are creating and removing this cumbersome process. It is cleaner and should be faster. For the groupby, I would need to look but never used it before.

Comment: I tried to replicate it by changing the value ``s`` to the list I'm currently using and by changing ``i[:-1]`` to ``i[0]``, since for what I got from this code, the ``i[:-1]`` in the accepted answer is used for the date value. But then, I get the error ``could not convert string to float: '-'``. But the date format in my code is exactly the same as in the links answer. If I keep it ``i[:-1]`` I get this error: ``could not convert string to float: '07-05-2015'``

Answer (score 1):

This code is easier for understanding:

```
l = [['05-05-2015', -40], ['05-05-2015', 30], ['07-05-2015', -75], ['05-05-2015', -40], ['05-05-2015', 120], ['07-05-2015', -150]]

result = {}

for entry in l:
    #  if date is not in dictionary, adding it to dictionary, other way making summation 
    if entry[0] not in result:
        result[entry[0]]=entry[1]
    else:
        result[entry[0]]+=entry[1]
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about a way to make this code, but I didn't had the sintax in my mind to make it work

Answer (score 0):

try grouped by and sum

```
lst = [['05-05-2015', -40], ['05-05-2015', 30], ['07-05-2015', -75], ['05-05-2015', -40], ['05-05-2015', 120], ['07-05-2015', -150]]

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','Amount'])
for item in lst:
    print(item)
    df=df.append({'Date':item[0],'Amount':item[1]},ignore_index=True)
    
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
grouped=df.groupby(df.index)['Amount'].sum()

res=[[item[0],item[1]] for item in grouped.items()]

print(res)
```

output:

```
[['05-05-2015', 70], ['07-05-2015', -225]]
```