# Apply custom functions to groupby pandas

Tags: pandas

I know there are questions/answers about how to use custom function for groupby in pandas but my case is slightly different.

My data is

```
  group_col       val_col
0         a    [1, 2, 34]
1         a        [2, 4]
2         b  [2, 3, 4, 5]

data = {'group_col': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'b'}, 'val_col': {0: [1, 2, 34], 1: [2, 4], 2: [2, 3, 4, 5]}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

What I am trying to do is to group by `group_col`, then sum up the length of lists in `val_col` for each group. My desire output is

```
a     5
b     4
```

I wonder I can do this in pandas?

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514009/i-want-to-group-my-list-of-lists-by-date-and-sum-the-values-where-the-dates-matc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
df['val_col'].str.len().groupby(df['group_col']).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('group_col')['val_col'].sum().str.len()
```

Output:

```
group_col
a    5
b    4
Name: val_col, dtype: int64
```